# Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertex. $G$ is unicyclic if, and only if, has $n$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory

I thought on using the fact that a tree with $n$ vertex always has $n-1$ edges, but I couldn't prove that if you add a edge to a tree it becomes a unicyclic graph and vice versa.

Comment: As stated, it's false. It is true for connected graphs though.

Comment: Specifically, for example, for $n=6$ the disjoint union of two triangles is a counterexample.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to write the "connected graph with n vertex"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was noted in the comments, the equivalence holds in general only for connected graphs, as among disconnected graphs there are counterexamples. For instance, the graph consisting of two disjoint triangles has $6$ vertices, $6$ edges, and two cycles.

Attack it from the other direction, by subtracting edges rather than adding them. Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n$ vertices. Suppose first that $G$ has $n$ edges; $G$ is not a tree, since it has one edge too many, so it has a cycle. On the other hand, removing any edge will leave a tree, which has no cycles, so $G$ can have only one cycle.

Now suppose that $G$ does not have $n$ edges. $G$ cannot have fewer than $n-1$ edges, as then it would not be connected. If $G$ has $n-1$ edges, it’s a tree and therefore acyclic. If $G$ has more than $n$ edges, it is not a tree and therefore has a cycle. Remove one edge from that cycle; the resulting graph still has at least $n$ edges, so it still has a cycle, and therefore $G$ must have at least two cycles.

Comment: thanks sir for help

Comment: @ILoveMath: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How did the comments prove that the statement is true **only** for connected graphs????

Comment: @mathworker21: I didn’t say that the comments **proved** it; I said that it was **stated** in the comments. Are you objecting to *only* on the grounds that there are unicyclic graphs with the same number of edges as vertices? That’s a bit of a quibble, since the *if and only if* statement, being implicitly universally quantified, is true for connected graphs and false for disconnected graphs, but if that is the objection, I’ll be happy to change *true* to *true in general*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see it stated in the comments. --------- "Are you objecting to *only* on the grounds that there are unicyclic graphs with the same number of edges as vertices?" What? ----------- "That’s a bit of a quibble, since the if and only if statement, being implicitly universally quantified, is true for connected graphs and false for disconnected graphs, but if that is the objection, I’ll be happy to change true to true in general." I don't know what most of what you said means, and I don't see what "true in general" would mean if you follow it by only. You obviously need to

Comment: delete the word "only". The comments just said it's false for some non-connected graph...

Comment: @mathworker21: Precisely. And I proved in the answer that it’s true for connected ones.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I honestly have no idea what you're saying. Where was it stated or proven that the result is **only true for connected graphs**?

Comment: @mathworker21: Is it your contention that my first sentence is asserting that the comments noted both that the proposition is false in general for disconnected graphs **and** that it is true for connected graphs? That is a somewhat unidiomatic understanding that ignores the context, but if that **is** your objection, I can alter my first sentence to accommodate it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Whether is assets that the statement is true for connected graphs is ambiguous I think. But it obviously says that the proposition is false for non-connected graphs (that's what 'only' means).

Comment: @mathworker21: No, it says that the statement that ‘a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices is unicyclic **if and only if** it has $n$ edges’ is false for disconnected graphs. And it is false: it asserts that being unicyclic and having equal numbers of vertices and edges are equivalent, and in the class of disconnected graphs they are not. The fact that there some disconnected graphs in which they happen to coincide is irrelevant: the existence of disconnected graphs in which they do not coincide is sufficient to show that the asserted equivalence is false for that class of graphs.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you're being ridiculous. I could also say "it's true only for a single edge". Indeed, if we look at the collection of graphs that are not just a single edge, then the equivalence fails, since the disjoint union of two triangles is in that collection. When someone says that something is true only for connected graphs, then they mean it fails for all disconnected graphs. And it was nowhere noted that the OP's statement is false for every single disconnected graph.

Comment: @mathworker21: No, I’m taking context into account and reading with an understanding of the actual assertion in question, and I rather think that most native speakers with the relevant mathematical background would understand the assertion precisely as I intended it. However, I will go so far as to change it to *the equivalence holds in general only for connected graphs, as among disconnected graphs there are counterexamples*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok, then you're fine with me saying "the equivalence holds in general only for a single edge"